# Handlebars Nested Each Statement

Tags: handlebars.js

I am attempting nest an each statement to handle the two objects that are available within my view. There is a relationship between the two objects with the `userId` on the `card` as the connection to the `userId` on the `user` table, which might be how this could work. I figure that I might have to end up registering a helper to have this work, but I'm not sure where to start. I attempted to bypass this process with the following handlebars syntax, but I get `TypeError: inverse is not a function`:

```
{{#each this.fullNameSlug ../user.fullNameSlug}}
            <h5>{{this.fullNameSlug}}</h5>
{{/each}}
```

Here is the full view:

```
{{#each card}}
<div class="row">
    <div class="card col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="card-date">
            <p class="card-date">{{this.cardDateSlug}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{this.title}}</h3>
            {{#each this.fullNameSlug ../user.fullNameSlug}}
            <h5>{{this.fullNameSlug}}</h5>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
{{/each}}
```

Here is the route with the two objects (card, user) that are accessible in the view:

```
/*====   /  ====*/

appRoutes.route('/') 

    .get(function(req, res){
        models.Card.findAll({
            order: 'annotationDate DESC',
            include: [{
                model: models.User,
                where: { organizationId: req.user.organizationId },
                attributes: ['organizationId', 'userId', 'fullNameSlug']
            }],
            limit: limitAmount.limit
        }).then(function(annotation){
            res.render('pages/app/activity-feed.hbs',{
                card: card,
                user: req.user
            });
        });
    })
```

**Card object:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var path = require('path');
var moment = require('moment');

var Card = sequelize.define('card', {
    cardId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'card_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    cardDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'card_date',
        isDate: true
    },
    reportLink: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        field: 'report_link'
    },
    fileAttachment: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'file_attachment'
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'user_id'
    },
    discoverySourceId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'discovery_source_id'
    }
},

 {
    freezeTableName: true,
    getterMethods: {
        cardDateSlug: function(){
            var date = new Date(this.getDataValue('annotationDate'));
            var momentDate = moment(date).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY"); 

            return momentDate;

        }
    },
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Card.belongsTo(db.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'}),
        }
    }
});
    return Card;
}
```

**User object:**

```
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field:'user_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        isEmail: true,
        unique: true,
        set: function(val) {
            this.setDataValue('email', val.toLowerCase());
        }
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: true
    },
    authenticationToken: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'authentication_token'
    },
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'reset_password_token'
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'reset_password_expires'
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    getterMethods: {
        fullNameSlug: function(){
            var fullName = this.getDataValue('firstName') + ' ' + this.getDataValue('lastName');
            return fullName;
        }
    },
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            User.belongsToMany(db.Organization, { through: 'member', foreignKey: 'user_id'})
        },
        generateHash: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        },
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        validPassword: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        },
    },  
});
    return User;
}
```

Comment: You should share what the `card` and `user` data objects looks like. They don't sound like collections, so you probably shouldn't be `each`ing them.

Comment: And perhaps share your expected output also. It is unclear to me what you are intending.

Comment: I added in the card and user objects. The expected output is to loop through each card record and present the data associated with that record, while also looping through the right user information on the user table that is associated with the record presented.

Comment: I don't see where `card` is assigned to. Should it not be assigned the value of the `annotation`? And the `user` object looks to be the requesting user, not a collection of users.